# How to serve GWT static files from a CDN

Tags: gwt, cdn, same-origin-policy

I am trying to figure out how to serve my GWT files from a CDN instead of from a tomcat server.

I started with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="no-index, no-follow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>My Site</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bcmjs/bcmjs.nocache.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="gwt_div">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And modified the javascript import to use the CDN url, from this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bcmjs/bcmjs.nocache.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uoo9w.cloudfront.net/bcmjs/bcmjs.nocache.js"></script>
```

Hoorah! The js downloads, UIBinder widgets are visible, but RPC fails.

The problem seems to be that `GWT.getModuleBase` returns the URL of the Javascript (uoo9w.cloudfront.net) instead of the host page (mysite.example.com), which breaks things like the URL used for RPC requests.

<strike>`GWT.getModuleBaseForStaticFiles` seems to be a method built allow CDN use, but I can't find documentation about it.</strike> *(See comments)*

Does anyone know of the correct way to set up GWT to serve from a CDN and send RPC request to the host page's domain?

Side Note:

Since the CDN has a different domain name and path, I was worried there were going to be problems involving the Same Origin Policy, but since the GWT host page is served on the same domain as all the RPC requests, this is not a problem. (ie. Window.Location is the same domain as the RPC)

Comment: FYI `getModuleBaseForStaticFiles` has been introduced for Super Dev Mode: static files are served by the SuperDevMode CodeServer, but `getModuleBaseURL` is your own server that also serves `getHostPageBaseURL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT sets the url of RPCs pointing to the `src` attribute of the `modulename.nocache.js` script-tag instead of the `location` of your document.

The normal way to fix it is that you change the base url of your `rpc` service to point to the `location` of your html file

```
GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
((ServiceDefTarget)greetingService)
   .setServiceEntryPoint("http://hostname_of_your_document/modulename/greet");
```

NOTE: in this case you are not doing *crossdomain* since your `.html` and your `services` are in the same host.

OPTIONALLY, if the `services` weren't in the same host than the `.html` file, you were doing *crossdomain*, so you might configure your servlet to support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). The best way is to configure a filter in your `web.xml`

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.example.server.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

For the filter class you can take the example I did for the [gwtquery Ajax documentation](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax#CORS_%28Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing%29)

Comment: Thanks, the first part is correct, but if you read my question closely, you will see that CORS is not required because the "Host page" is not served from the CDN. So, the domain from the `Window.Location` property matches the domain of the xmlhttprequest. Upvoted anyways because the CORS piece is probably useful for many other people.

Comment: Gotcha. So you have to set the serviceEntryPoint manually since afaik, gwt computes the hostname based on the src of the `script` tag in the document matching your `module_name.nocache.js`. Other options could be to rewrite the algorithm used by gwt to compute the name, or to place an empty script with the same name and different host in the document just before the real `nocache` script.

Comment: I accepted your answer (I figured you could use the rep, plus I'm stoked about GWTQuery). Can you update your answer to indicate that CORS is Optional?

Answer (score 2):

So the answer seems to be manually call `ServiceDefTarget.setServiceEntryPoint()` for every RPC interface

Here is the code I used to replace the `moduleBaseURL` with the url of the host page. It let me use the existing `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` annotations on all my `RemoteService` interfaces.

```
public static native String getHostpageUrl()/*-{
   return $wnd.location.protocol + "//" + $wnd.location.host + "/";
}-*/;

GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);

ServiceDefTarget serviceDefTarget= ((ServiceDefTarget)greetingService);
String oldUrl = serviceDefTarget.getServiceEntryPoint();
String newServiceEntryPoint =  oldUrl.startsWith(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()) ? 
        getBaseUrl() + "module/" + oldUrl.substring(GWT.getModuleBaseURL().length(), value.length()) 
       : oldUrl;
serviceDefTarget.setServiceEntryPoint(newServiceEntryPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this detailed account of the four aspects you'll need to update to run a GWT app off a CDN like AWS CloudFront.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/4eNY2RiLH1k

Hope that helps.